# Show Me "All Opportunities" randomly filters the data by Role

Tags: custom-reports, matrix

I am experiencing some major frustration with a matrix report. I have a report that shows opportunities grouped by Closed date and then by a Custom grouping value

I would like the report show include All Opportunities

I am using a Custom report type

The problem I am having is that even though I select **Show Me "All Opportunities"** the report for some reason automatically changes it to **Show Me "All Opportunities under role: XXXXX"** the role is not always the same each time this happens

[image]

I have tried rebuilding the report type, the reports, I've cleared my browser cache too many times to count. and still the report changes.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can set the report to just include All Opps not filtered by Role?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as per the design.

> A Standard Report Type will show all the Opportunities the Running User can see, and that meet the criteria.

> A Custom Report Type will only show Opportunities owned by a User with the same Role as or a Role below them in the Hierarchy. In this case if the missing Opportunities are owned by a User with a Role higher in the Hierarchy, the Running User will need to click that Role in the Hierarchy selector (this can be found in the report detail page under its name).

Please find the related [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385379&type=1) for the same.

Comment: Thanks @SaiPraveen, that clears up the issue, a deeply frustrating as it is, as it limits the flexibility of custom report types.